# angular $watch function not working with model change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

Hi friends I'm new into angular and getting stuck while creating a example of `$watch` function. I just want to push data into existing modal(json data) and the changes in model will reflect into `view`. Please check my code below or check [**fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/4eLaavu0/3/)

**SCRIPT**

```
var list = [{
                        name: 'Jon',
                        joining_date:'2015-10-23', 
                        age: 23
                    },
                    {
                        name:'Viki', 
                        joining_date:'2015-01-24',
                        age: 20
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Abc',
                        joining_date:'2015-10-25',
                        age: 43
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'XYZ', 
                        joining_date:'2015-10-21',
                        age: 21
                }];


var empApp = angular.module('emp-list', []);
empApp.controller('emp-table',function($scope){
    $scope.data = list;

    $scope.dateFormate = function(joinDate){
        return new Date(joinDate)
    }
       // PUSHING DATA IN EXISTING MODAL
        setInterval(function(){
            $scope.data.push({name: 'XYZ', joining_date:'2015-10-21',age: 21})
        }, 1000);
        // USING $WATCH FUNCTION
        $scope.$watch('data');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` is outside of angular's scope, thus the view is unawre of your changes. Use angular built-in `$interval`, like this:

```
empApp.controller('emp-table',function($scope, $interval) {

$interval(function(){
        $scope.data.push({name: 'XYZ', joining_date:'2015-10-21',age: 21})
    }, 1000);
```

Now, regarding your `$watch` expression - it is currently watching data for any changes made to it. Using `setInterval`, the `$watch` will not notice any changes made on the list. After switching to `$interval` the `$watch` can be used freely:

```
$scope.$watch('data', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log("current data: " + newValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with setInterval is correct, but not complete. The $scope.$watch expression checks property $scioe.data by reference, since Array.prototype.push mutates the array - reference is not change and $scope.$watch does not detect any changes. To overcome this issue you need to pass third argument to $watch method - for deep check:

```
$scope.$watch('data', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log("current data: " + newValue);
}, true);
```

Or alternatively you can change the reference of $scope.data (this option is less performance costly)
e.g.:

```
$interval(function(){
    $scope.data = $scope.data.concat({name: 'XYZ', joining_date:'2015-10-21',age: 21});
}, 1000);
```